# Failure to find com.oracle.state-management:state-management-parent:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT

Tags: oracle, maven, weblogic

I can't remember what I did to cause this problem. When I try to run `mvn clean install`, I get the following output:

```
mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building search Maven Webapp 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:12.1.2 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.895 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-05-29T21:55:34+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/154M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project search: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.ws:search:war:1.0: Failed to collect dependencies at com.oracle.weblogic:weblogic-server-pom:pom:12.1.2-0-0 -> com.oracle.weblogic:com.oracle.state-management.e
xecutor-internal-api_12.1.2:jar:12.1.2: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.oracle.weblogic:com.oracle.state-management.executor-internal-api_12.1.2:jar:12.1.2: Failure to find com.oracle.state-management:state-management-parent:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT in http://10.68
.20.32:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of snapshots has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

The attempt to find `com.oracle.state-management.executor-internal-api_12.1.2:jar:12.1.2` (Note the version: 12.1.2) fails because it originates from the dependency `com.oracle.state-management.executor-internal-api_12.1.2` (version 12.1.2 too) while this dependency's pom has the following portion:

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>state-management-parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.oracle.state-management</groupId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../../parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
```

What surprises me is that there is another version for this dependency (`com.oracle.state-management.executor-internal-api_12.1.2`) which is **12.1.2-0-0**, I believe that this is the right version to refer to, not **12.1.2**

What I think supports my assumption is that the output mentions that it failed to find **sfl4j** dependency with the version **12.1.2** !!

```
[WARNING] The POM for org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:12.1.2 is missing, no dependency information available
```

I refer to weblogic's dependency this way

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
    <artifactId>weblogic-server-pom</artifactId>
    <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

How can I fix that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some unearthly reason, weblogic's dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
    <artifactId>weblogic-server-pom</artifactId>
    <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

had the following version for it's dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
    <artifactId>weblogic</artifactId>
    <version>[12.1.2,12.1.3)</version>
</dependency>
```

To resolve this, I replaced all `[12.1.2,12.1.3)` occurrences with `12.1.2-0-0` and now I can `install` my project again.

I would really appreciate it if someone tells me why was the **POM** generated this way ?!